# problem in parsing a xml file

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I am using following code to get values of a particular tag in xml:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory  =  DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
Document doc = null;
DocumentBuilder docbuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
doc = docbuilder.parse(jobFilePath);
NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("xyz");
System.out.println("nodelist Lengthhhhhhhhhh = " + nodeList.getLength());

for (int i=0;i<nodeList.getLength();i++) {
    Node c= nodeList.item(i);
    System.out.println("val =" + c.getNodeValue());
}
```

input xml is

```
<abc> 
        <xyz p="Layouts">a</xyz>
        <xyz p="Layouts">b</xyz>
        <xyz p="Layouts">3</xyz>
</abc>
```

Output is

```
nodelist Lengthhhhhhhhhh 3
val = null
val = null
val = null
```

why is it coming out null?

Comment: i wan to fetch values of tag xyx , op should be a b 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
System.out.println("val =" + c.getNodeValue());
```

into:

```
System.out.println("val =" + c.getTextContent());
```

Comment: c.getTextContent()) worked ! but i wonder why c.getNodeValue is not working?

Comment: `c` references the whole node `<xyz p="Layouts">a</xyz>` that has no node value (see [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html) for more details).  You could actually get the first (and only) child of that node as well and get that one's node value, that would be a text node containing a/b/3.  But since you know what your element looks like, you can directly call `getTextContent()` on your node.

Answer (score 2):

Going out on a limb here... but from my memories of DOM manipulation in Javascript, you need to use:

```
 Node c= nodeList.item(i).getFirstChild();
```

As the firstChild contains the actual value of the tag itself.

Answer (score 1):

Like others have stated `getTextContent()` will provide you with the contents of the Text nodes of the `xyz` elements.

The actual reason for this behavior of `getNodeValue()` that you've asked for, is specified in the [DOM Level 2 Core API](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1950641247):

> The attributes nodeName, nodeValue and
>   attributes are included as a mechanism
>   to get at node information without
>   casting down to the specific derived
>   interface. In cases where there is no
>   obvious mapping of these attributes
>   for a specific nodeType (e.g.,
>   **nodeValue for an Element** or attributes
>   for a Comment), **this returns null**.

When the line `Node c= nodeList.item(i);` is executed, the Node `c` contains an object of type Element (with nodeName=`xyz`, nodeValue=`null`). It is the child Text node of these `xyz` elements that actually contain the values `a`, `b` and `3`. The method `getTextContent()` returns the value of the text nodes of given element, where as `getNodeValue()` just returns the nodeValue attribute as applicable to a particular node.

The DOM Level 2 Core API also specifies what these values are, for the other types of nodes in the Document. Note that the nodeValue for text nodes happens to be the content of the node.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try this:

c.getTextContent()